# Rider related to Exponents

Tags: linear-algebra

If $m \neq n$ and $\frac 1 {m+n}(\frac 1 m+\frac 1 n)=(m^x)(n^y)$ then show that $x+y+2=0$.

I reduced the left hand side of the equation to $\frac 1 {mn}=(m^x)(n^y)$.Guide me to move further.

Answer (score 0):

your starting Point is good, write
$$m^{-1}\cdot n^{-1}=m^x\cdot n^y$$ thus....

Answer (score 0):

Given that: $\frac 1 {m+n}(\frac 1 m+\frac 1 n)=(m^x)(n^y)$.

You said you got to the point  $\frac 1 {mn}=(m^x)(n^y)$ which then implies $m^{-1}n^{-1} = (m^x)(n^y)$

Compare the exponents of $m$ and $n$ on both sides, so you get $x = y = -1$ which gives $x+y+2=0$.